# Does the Grand Priest tell about the best fighter prize?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I have watched the first 92 episodes of *Dragon Ball Super*. At the start of Episode 78, the Grand Priest explains to Goku and Beerus that the best fighter will receive Super Dragon Balls. But at the end of the episode, the Grand Priest does not explain the best fighter reward to other universes. Instead, he announces that low-level mortal level universes will be erased upon losing.

Does the Grand Priest explain the best fighter prize after Episode 92? I don't care about spoilers now because my brother says "You didn't watch DBS properly, the Grand Priest mentioned the prize for winning the tournament many times". But I disagreed on that.

Comment: Are you specifically asking whether the Grand Priest mentions the "best fighter" prize to the other universes' fighters?

Comment: As per the discussion on [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/67308/35679), when you say "best fighter", do you mean the overall winner of the tournament?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember if the Grand Priest explained the best prize to fighters on screen, but he had to do it either on screen or off screen, because people from other universes knew about it and they had their own wishes, for example, Jiren wanted to resurrect his former martial arts teacher.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **"Best fighter reward"**

- The winner of the tournament is granted one limitless wish from the
  Super Dragon Balls. In the anime, if the warrior wishes for something
  selfish, then both Zenos will erase everything
- When all 10 warriors of a Universe are eliminated, that Universe, its
  deities (barring the angels of said universe), and its inhabitants
  are immediately erased by Zeno and Future Zeno.

Comment: Wouldn't the winner of the tournament logically be the best fighter? That certainly seems to be what OP is referring to in the question.

Comment: @F1Krazy winner is not logically it is not the best fighter as well,  we all know goku and jiren are best fighter but Android 19 won the tournament because he survived... but what OP is asking is the best fighter reward. there is no such reward mentioned by them...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli It's not about what the actual rules were. The question is on what grand priest actually said to Goku and Beerus vs to other universes before the starting of tournament.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're under the impression that Grand Priest will choose the best fighter from each universe. But, with *Best Fighter* he meant the best fighter from all universes combined, which is the last man standing in the battle royale of the universes, and all the other participating universes except the winner universe will be erased.

Comment: No. I'm not under the impression you mentioned. I know exactly what grand priest meant by the best fighter. My question was simply that grand priest didn't explain anything about super dragon balls to other universes. Instead, he said that lower level universes will be erased. I think he also told to other universes that there is no prize on winning.